# How to create a List of objects (i.e. singletons) in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

suppose I have the following code

```
trait T

object O extends T
```

Now suppose I want to create a `List[T]` of size 10, that is populated by O.
In other words, the list should look like `(O, O, O,..., O)`.

Trying to do the usual Scala way of `(1 until 10) map (x => O) toList` creates a `List[O.type]`.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The code `val list:List[T] = (1 until 10) map (x => O) toList` works fine for me.  Also, `List.fill(10)(O)` is probably neater...

Comment: It creates the list properly. List[O.type] is the type of the resulting list, not the list itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that scala inferred the most specific type. In you case, the specific type of the `O` object: `O.type`. So you need to precise the type.

By the way, tt's not the scala way to do it, it's better to do:

```
List.fill(10)(O)
```

But it won't produce a `List[T]` either. So you need to do:

```
List.fill[T](10)(O)
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify your type explicitly:

```
val l: List[T] = (1 until 10) map (x => O) toList
```